# How to output SAS Macro variable value

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have written a simple macro and applied it in a simple SAS data step to illustrate an issue I am having with viewing output.

Macro:

```
%macro test_func(var=);
%put &var;
%mend;
```

Data step:

```
data test_data_step;
value = 0;
%test_func(var = value);
run;
```

My issue is that the output I see is just the string `value` rather than the value held in the variable whose name is equal to that string.

I believe I have a vague understanding as to why SAS is doing this, but I don't know how to get it to give the desired value (namely `0` in this case). So how would I be able to achieve that functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the difference between `%put` and `put`.

Do you want to see the contents of the macro variable `&var`?  Then use `%put(&var)`.

If, however, you want to see the contents of the SAS data step variable whose name is stored in `&var`, then use `put(&var)`.

As such I would rewrite this:

```
%macro test_func(var=);
put &var.;
%mend;
```

And now this works as you expect:

```
data test_data_step;
  value = 0;
  %test_func(var = value)
run;
```

(Note one other minor change - the removal of the `;` after `%test_func` - it is unnecessary, and while usually not a big deal, it can cause problems if you get in the habit of putting it there.)

Comment: +1. Thanks @Joe! As usual, your answers are brief yet clear and instructive - I learn something every time! One issue though: my main interest in outputting the variable value was to troubleshoot my macro. With this approach I would have multiple non macro statements in the macro I am troubleshooting, leading to other errors. So I'm left wondering how to proceed. I could ask another question here but I would like to at least try to figure things out myself. What would you recommend? Thanks again!

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing.  But ultimately, the macro language (`%put` etc.) don't get to have access to actual values; so you'll have to figure out how to put the debugging statements in there in ways that it doesn't cause problems, probably.  One thing I often do is include debugging code in the main code body itself (whether that's actually in a macro or not) and then include `%if` blocks that check a variable `&debug` - if `&debug=Y` then run the debugging code.